# paypointgateway module stuck on redirect page

Tags: checkout, payment-gateway

I have the new paypoint module installed and it appears to be working, it can be configured and chosen as a payment option using the hosted method.

However, once the "place order" button is pressed and one would expect it to redirect to paypoint for payment, it just goes to a blank page with url`/paypointgateway/hosted/redirect/` and sits there.

There is nothing in the paypoint log, the magento log or the apache log.

```
UPDATE:
```

In answer to the comment, the redirctAction is:

```
public function redirectAction() {
  return parent::_redirect_action(__METHOD__);
}
```

And the parent is:

```
protected function _redirect_action($child_method) {
     $html = 
        $this
            ->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(
                $this->_redirectBlock,
                null,
                array('paymentMethodInstance' => $this->_getPaymentMethodInstance())
            )
            ->toHtml();
     $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
}
```

So I'll look into the layout file.

```
UPDATE 2:
```

Ok, have narrowed it down to this part returning nothing, well, a zero length string.:

```
$html = 
        $this
            ->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(
                $this->_redirectBlock,
                null,
                array('paymentMethodInstance' => $this->_getPaymentMethodInstance())
            )
            ->toHtml();
```

Note also that `$this->_redirectBlock` (a string) and `$this->_getPaymentMethodInstance()` (an object) are non-empty.

Comment: Check what the method `redirectAction()` from the `HoesteController` is supposed to do. Maybe there is something wrong with it. If all it does is `loadLayout()->renderLayout()` it might be something wrong with your layout file.

Comment: well...the `_redirect_action` method seams like a good place to start debugging. According to the code you updated a block should be created and displayed. Check to see what class is that block (`$this->_redirectBlock`), see if the class exists, and what it should do.

Comment: Thanks... the redirect block is `paypointgateway/redirect_hostedredirect` as set in the first controller. This seems to point to `PayPoint_Gateway_Block_Redirect_Hostedredirect` which sets a `$_redirect_form_id` only, but extends a block which has a `_toHtml` which returns the html for a page with an auto-submitting form.

Comment: Seams right. You say there is nothing in the Magento log, but is the log enabled? If it is then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @marius essentially the _toHtml() function is not being called from the `PayPoint_Common_Block_Redirect_Hostedredirect` file. Any thoughts on this? The file is being loaded, but that function not run.

Comment: If the block is a child of class `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and `_toHtml()` does not have any output, could be because there is no template set for the block. (but I'm just shooting in the dark here)

Comment: It's is far, far worse than that! This module had several issues, and whilst solving an earlier one I disabled one of the sub-modules... so no toHtml... oh dear. Thanks for your help. If you write your comments up I'll mark it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams like the suggestions in the comments were on the right track. Maybe they can serve someone as steps to check in a similar issue:

- Check what the method `redirectAction()` from the `HoesteController` is
  supposed to do. Maybe there is something wrong with it. If all it
  does is `loadLayout()->renderLayout()` it might be something wrong with
  your layout file
- If the block is a child of class `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and
  `_toHtml()` does not have any output, could be because there is no template set for the block.